# How to open a link automatically after Scanning QR Code in Flutter without clicking some Button

Tags: flutter, qr-code

I have a little question about QR Code Scanning in Flutter. How to open a URL website after successfully reading data from the QR Code?

I use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) package for using QR Code, and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-installing-tab-) for open a URL and this is my function to checking the value of data from QR code is a URL or not and if it's a URL, then run the function to open the website.

```
checkingValue() {
    if (_result != null || _result != "") {
      if (_result.contains("https") || _result.contains("http")) {
        return _launchURL(_result);
      } else {
        Toast.show("Invalide URL", context,
            duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  _launchURL(String urlQRCode) async {
    String url = urlQRCode;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

The `_result` variable is a String to get a value from QR code data.

And this is the full of my code:

```
class _ScannerPageState extends State<ScannerPage> {

  String _password;
  String _result = "";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        _result = qrResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          _result = "Camera permission was denied";
          Toast.show(_result, context,
              duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _result = "Unknown Error $ex";
          Toast.show(_result, context,
              duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        _result = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
        Toast.show(_result, context,
            duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        _result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        Toast.show(_result, context,
            duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return PopUp(
                content: "Are you sure want to exit?",
                cancelText: "No",
                acceptText: "Yes",
                onTapCancel: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                onTapAccept: () async {
                  await SessionManager().removeSession();//
                  await SystemNavigator.pop();
                },
              );
            }
        );
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_result.contains("https") || _result.contains("http") ? _result : "Invalid URL"),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          label: Text("Scan"),
          onPressed: () => _scanQR(),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),
    );
  }

  checkingValue() {
    if (_result != null || _result != "") {
      if (_result.contains("https") || _result.contains("http")) {
        return _launchURL(_result);
      } else {
        Toast.show("Invalide URL", context,
            duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  _launchURL(String urlQRCode) async {
    String url = urlQRCode;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

}
```

So, where I put the `checkingValue()` function for running it after scanning the QR Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `qrResult` to `checkingValue` method

```
Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      checkingValue(qrResult);
     //....
    }
```

`checkingValue` method

```
checkingValue(String url) {
    //...
}
```

or call `checkingValue()` after

```
setState(() {_result = qrResult;});
checkingValue();
//...
```